# How to loop over a python list using the index numbers?

Tags: python, arrays, list, for-loop, indexing

I was trying to loop over a list in python using the indices but it drops error. Can you guys help me out with this? What could be the syntax that could fix this ?

```
abs = [10,20,40] 

for i in abs: 
    new_abs = abs[i]+ abs[i+1]
    print(new_abs)
```

So, i have managed to use hard code for the temporary use.

```
abs = [10,20,40] 
new_abs = [ abs[0], abs[0]+ abs[1] , abs[1]+abs[2] ] 
print(new_abs)
```

Can you please, let me know the proper syntax to loop over this index numbers?

Comment: What are you trying to do?

Comment: How to i run new_abs in a loop?

Comment: `i` should be the indices, you're currently looping on the values. Use `for i in range(len(abs)-1):`

Comment: didn't  get you. may be you would like to define what `new_abs` is ? `for i in range(len(abs)): print(abs[i])` syntax iterate through list with the help of indexes. and `for i in abs: print(i)` will directly print your elements in abs.

Comment: `print(abs[0])` followed by `for index, item in enumerate(abs[:-1]): print(item+abs[index+1])`  would be the solution to your summation problem -  `enumerate(abs[:-1])` to avoid IndexError for the last element - at least thats the logic of your second code parts

Answer (score 5):

Looping over lists in python you have few options

```
for i in abs:
   print(i)
```

will print you all items in the lists.
If you want to loop over lists items with indexes you can use

```
for index, item in enumerate(abs):
    print(index, item)
```

that will lop over each item and will provide you the index number of the item in the list and the current item.